# How to define Enums for Switch case where positon is related

Tags: java, android, enums

I have to define ENUMs for all Switch cases. I am not sure how to relate enums when it comes to positions. Below is my code:

```
public enum Choice {
    A, B, C
}

public void selectItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        // Dashboard
        case 0:
        break;
        case 1:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't `position` be an enum type?

Comment: Choice.values() will get you an array of the enums (with their ordinal positions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to transform int position to respective ENUM. Every enum value has a ordinal by default. Here in Choice enum, A has ordinal zero and so on.

```
public class TestMain {

  public enum Choice {
    A, B, C
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    selectItem(0);
  }

  public static void selectItem(int position) {
    Choice selectedChoice = null;
    selectedChoice = getChoiceFromPosition(position, selectedChoice);

    switch (selectedChoice) {
      //Dashboard
      case A:
        System.out.println(selectedChoice.ordinal());
        break;
      case B:
        break;
      case C:
        break;
    }
  }

  private static Choice getChoiceFromPosition(int position, Choice selectedChoice) {
    for(Choice c : Choice.values()){
      if(c.ordinal() == position) {
        selectedChoice =c;
      }
    }
    return selectedChoice;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. But my andorid studio is warning me to not use "null" for "selectedChoice". Says it is risky

Comment: Yes, you can do two things then,

1. Add a Entry(may be last) in ENUM as UNKNOWN and initialise selectedChoice as UNKNOWN. In switch case when it goes to case of UNKNOWN you can  throw a exception or notify caller/user that it is not a valid position

2. After you call getChoiceFromPosition() and selectedChoice still remains null then  throw a exception or notify caller/user that it is not a valid position

Answer (score 5):

do instead use the **enum** directly in the switch

```
public void selectItem(Choice x) {
    switch (x) {
        // Dashboard
        case A:
        break;
        case B:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally, this is bad idea. However to convert an ordinal into its enum represantation you might want to do this:

```
Choice value = Choice.values()[position];
```

Below you can find clipping from the **[Item 31: Use instance fields instead of ordinals](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=Effective+Java+ordinals&source=bl&ots=yZLlKft5UX&sig=zbQuiBv2FDK5AZUArOcBDny3ixc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi11pKd0pnUAhXhFJoKHajwAdMQ6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=Effective%20Java%20ordinals&f=false)** (Effective Java, page 158, Joshua Bloch), where described how to avoid using ordinals.

> Never derive a value associated with an enum from its ordinal; store
>   it in an instance field instead
>
> ```
> // Abuse of ordinal to derive an associated value - DON'T DO THIS
> public enum Ensemble {
>    SOLO,   DUET,   TRIO, QUARTET, QUINTET,
>    SEXTET, SEPTET, OCTET, NONET,  DECTET;
>
>    public int numberOfMusicians() {
>       return ordinal() + 1;
>    }
> }
>
> public enum Ensemble {
>    SOLO(1), DUET(2), TRIO(3), QUARTET(4), QUINTET(5),
>    SEXTET(6), SEPTET(7), OCTET(8), DOUBLE_QUARTET(8),
>    NONET(9), DECTET(10), TRIPLE_QUARTET(12);
>
>    private final int numberOfMusicians;
>
>    Ensemble(int size) {
>       this.numberOfMusicians = size;
>    }
>
>    public int numberOfMusicians() {
>       return numberOfMusicians;
>    }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum Choice {
    A, B, C
}

public Choice selectItem(int position) {
    return Choice.values()[position];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try adding some methods into your enum to contain the logic.

```
public enum Choice {
    A, B, C;
    static Choice[] values = Choice.values(); //so array not created defined every time.

    public static Choice fromOrdinal(int position){
        if(position<values.length){
            return values[position];
        } 
        return A; //default
    }
}
```

// for example when a spinner is selected in android, it returns an int position.

// to map this position to an enum, you can call the fromOrdinal() method like below.

```
public void selectItem(int position) {
    switch (Choice.fromOrdinal(position)) {
        // Dashboard
        case A:
        break;
        case B:
        break;
        ...// the rest of your cases.
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "ordinal", rather than "cardinal".

Answer (score 0):

Many good answers here. Just adding one more that is quite elegant and worth considering.

You can make the `enum` do all of the work.

```
interface Selectable {
    public void selected();
}

public enum Choice implements Selectable {
    A {
        @Override
        public void selected() {
            System.out.println("We're all going to die!!!");
        }
    }, B{
        @Override
        public void selected() {
            System.out.println("Everyone lives forever");
        }
    }, C{
        @Override
        public void selected() {
            System.out.println("Nobody knows.");
        }
    };
}
```

This actually completely removes the the need for a `switch ... case` statement.